# Differential equation - solving for y.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ x\frac{dy}{dx} = y(y+1) $$

I'm unsure how to get rid of the two $y$'s I get further down.

I did $1/x\ dx = 1/ ( y^2+y )$.
After partial fractions
$$\ln x = \ln y - \ln (y - 1)$$

I have two $y$'s and I don't know how to get $y$ by itself. Help?

Comment: You'd get $\ln x+\ln c= \ln y-\ln{(y+1)}\implies \frac {y}{y+1}=cx$. Now solve for $y$. Thus $y(1-cx)=cx$.

Comment: I got lost in the step where you said solve for y.  But I get what you said before.

Comment: In the future, try and typeset your mathematics using MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about solving this ODE.
\begin{align}
x\frac{dy}{dx} &= y(y+1)\tag*{[given]} \\
\int\frac{dy}{y(y+1)} &= \int\frac{dx}{x}\tag*{[separate variables & integrate]} \\
\int\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)\,dy &= \int\frac{1}{x}\,dx\tag*{[partial fractions on LHS]} \\
\ln{|y|}-\ln{|y+1|} &= \ln{|x|}+C_1,\ C_1\in\mathbb{R}\tag*{[perform integration]} \\
\ln{\left|\frac{y}{y+1}\right|} &= \ln{|x|}+C\tag*{[simplify LHS]} \\
\left|\frac{y}{y+1}\right| &= \exp\left(\ln{|x|}+C\right)\tag*{[exponentiate]} \\
&= C_2|x|,\ C_2\in\mathbb{R}\tag*{[simplify RHS]} \\
&= C_2x,\ x\geq 0.\tag*{[choose $x\geq 0$]}
\end{align}
It doesn't look like there's a convenient way to express $y$ as an explicit function of $x$, so that's as far as I'll go. I hope this helps.

Comment: I found out the question is really weird. To solve it use y = xe^c(y+1)  (Transfer In(y+1) to the other side) . Expand, subtract the value xy^c. Now you can factorize out they to get the answer. The principle relies on multiplying the other side by y so you can subtract and factorize.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   x \frac{dy}{dx} &= y(y+1) \\
   \frac{dy}{y(y+1)} &= \frac{dx}{x} \\
   \frac{dy}{y} - \frac{dy}{y+1} &= \frac{dx}{x} \\
   &\phantom{n}\vdots
\end{align}